# Any free UML modeling tool that runs on native Win32?

Tags: uml

I know about [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/), an UML modeling tool that needs java to run.

I'm looking for something similar, but which doesn't need java.

Comment: Can I ask why the desire to avoid Java?  Argo is pretty good, and it even comes with a Web-start package - you can set it up for one-click access without needing to deal with command lines.  Just have a JRE with Web Start installed (and turn off automatic updates).

Comment: Because I have some homework to do using UML, I don't have installed JRE in my Win XP and I don't want to install it. And yes, if you will use UML regularly you must (at least) give a try to ArgoUML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try StarUML:
http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

Comment: StarUML is slow and weak. It wasn't able to import my project (it was obviously too large for him: 160k C++ lines). BOUML did this in 1 minute!

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [**GenMyModel**](http://www.genmymodel.com), to create UML-compliant models **online, without installing anything on your computer**. It's a new UML online tool allowing to design UML2 models, export them and generate code. As it's entirely web-based, you don't need Java to use it, only a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

[JUDE Community edition](http://jude.change-vision.com/jude-web/product/community.html) is terrific.  Does the round trip for Java 5 if that's your implementation language.

Answer (score 1):

**I strongly recommend** [BOUML](https://www.bouml.fr/). It's a free UML modelling application, which:

- is extremely fast (**fastest** UML tool ever created, check out [benchmarks](https://www.bouml.fr/benchmark.html)),
- has rock solid C++, Java, PHP and others import support,
- is multiplatform (Linux, Windows, other OSes),
- has a great SVG export support, which is important, because viewing large graphs in vector format, which scales fast in e.g. Firefox, is very convenient (you can quickly switch between "birds eye" view and class detail view),
- is full featured, impressively intensively developed (look at [development history](https://www.bouml.fr/historic.html), it's hard to believe that such fast progress is possible).
- supports plugins, has modular architecture (this allows [user contributions](https://www.bouml.fr/contrib.html), looks like BOUML community is forming up)

Believe me, there is no better tool. StarUML is a retarded turtle compared to BOUML. ArgoUML simply doesn't work. Dia is a ergonomy^-1 software.

Answer (score 0):

["Dia for Windows"](http://dia-installer.de/)

> Dia is inspired by the commercial Windows program 'Visio', though more geared towards informal diagrams for casual use. It can be used to draw many different kinds of diagrams. It currently has special objects to help draw entity relationship diagrams, UML diagrams, flowcharts, network diagrams, and many other diagrams. It is also possible to add support for new shapes by writing simple XML files, using a subset of SVG to draw the shape.

Answer (score 0):

This wiki list provides a pretty comprehensive list of free and pay UML tools, often you can tell if it runs natively in windows.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools

Oddly enough why whould you have a requirement to run natively? So just not Java.  Too bad you can't choose by features or capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

[Software Ideas Modeler (Non-Commercial Use)](http://www.softwareideas.net/)
It is a perfect CASE tool.